# How to move the sidebar in TwentyFifteen to the right?

Tags: themes, child-theme, theme-twenty-fifteen

Is it possible to move the sidebar in the TwentyFifteen theme to the right using a child theme and CSS only, or does it require changes to the theme itself? The main issue I'm running into is that I can get the sidebar on the right side in either the "default" or the "scrolled" scenario, but not in both (default uses position: relative and is what you get when the page loads, scrolled is set when the page is scrolled and changes the sidebar position to absolute.)

Comment: Look at the theme’s `rtl.css`. It does that.

Comment: Is not sufficient. If I try with the RTL tester, the sidebar *remains* on the left side. When I copy/pasted the relevant section out of the RTL.css, the sidebar did indeed switch over, but it would get broken again while scrolling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took the following from the `rtl.css` and applied them via [Magic Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/magic-widgets/) with additional `!important` keywords to an English site:

```
body:before {
    right: 0 !important;
    left: auto !important;
}
.sidebar {
    float: right !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    margin-left: -100% !important;
}
.site-content {
    float: right !important;
    margin-right: 29.4118% !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
}
.site-footer {
    float: right !important;
    margin: 0 35.2941% 0 0 !important;
}
```

This seems to work, even when you scroll down.

Comment: Not sufficient for me. I also had to add:
    
    body {
 direction: rtl;
    }

    .sidebar, .site-content, .site-footer {
 direction: ltr;
    }

Comment: @Anteru I assume that you know how the SE network works: If you got an addition, file an [edit] and explain the _why_ in an edit message. Thanks.

Comment: At least it wasn't enough in Firefox, when I would scroll down, the side bar would randomly disappear and reappear. The RTL/LTR trick seems to solve that. Oh and for the record: When putting this into a child theme, the `!important` are not needed.

Comment: Yep, get the same problem when i test it.

Comment: @Anteru - thanks a lot, your additional codes helped me too !

Comment: Unfortunately, this breaks the *responsiveness*, and the page looks broken on mobiles.

Comment: This is not/no longer working.

Answer (score 4):

You can add below code to your child theme.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 59.6875em) {
    .site-content {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0px;
        width: 70.5882%;
    }   
    .sidebar {
        float: right;
        right:0;
        margin-right: 0px;
        max-width: 413px;
        width: 29.4118%;
    }   
    body:before {
        right: 0;
        left:auto;
    }       
    .site-footer {
        margin: 0 0 0 6.1%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works based on my testing.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, as soon as I scroll and the JavaScript makes the sidebar sticky, it moves to the right. Probably because the JavaScript changes the position to "fixed", which together with the right:0 rule makes it stick to the right-hand side (and hence moves it, if window is wide enough.)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution breaks the responsiveness of the theme when used from a mobile. I had to wrap the accepted solution by toscho and Anteru in a `@media screen` as the original twentyfifteen template.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 59.6875em) {
  body:before {
    right: 0 !important;
    left: auto !important;
  }

  .sidebar {
    float: right !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    margin-left: -100% !important;
  }
  .site-content {
    float: right !important;
    margin-right: 29.4118% !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
  }
  .site-footer {
    float: right !important;
    margin: 0 35.2941% 0 0 !important;
  }

  body { direction: rtl; }
  .sidebar, .site-content, .site-footer { direction: ltr; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently extended a child theme from tips and tricks for the twenty fifteen theme and i thought i should share how you can move the sidebar to the right with you guys. in the extended child theme i removed the sidebar completely from the twenty fifteen theme as some people prefer to use it that way. You can download the child theme [here](http://wedevall.com/product/twenty-fifteen-child-no-sidebar/) and change the code to restore the sidebar to the right:

Change the following code:

```
.sidebar {
    float: none !important;
    margin-right: 0px;
    max-width: 413px;
    position: relative !important;
    width: 29.4118%;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    display: none;
}
```

to

```
.sidebar {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0px;
    max-width: 413px;
    position: relative !important;
    width: 29.4118%;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```